# i have set Enabled false in android listview but listview not scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll, disable

I am using listview multiple selection in android. I want to disable listview clickable and make false. I tried to set `setEnabled(false)` it's working but listview is not scrolling. My condition is only particular user to check and uncheck the items.

```
if (mycondition == true) {
   listview.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: You can achieve it from your list_row inside your Adapter.

Comment: You disable  listview touch event . so use adapter and do itemView.setEnabed(false)

Comment: i am using simple array adapter membersList.setChoiceMode(membersList.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                        membersList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Meeting.this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, memberCheckedList));

Comment: I would suggest trying RecyclerView for everything list/grid related

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shared any code, I am assuming this is what you want to do. Don't make entire ListView disabled which you are doing by adding `membersList.setEnabled(false);`

```
mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Meeting.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, memberCheckedList));
membersList.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);


membersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            View itemView = (View) mArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
            if (itemView != null) {
                itemView.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: bro i just want to disable a listview clickable for some user .. thats it

Comment: when i implement View.. i have getting this error "inconvertible types , cannot cast java.lang.String to android.view.View"

Comment: Then create custom ItemView and adapter. I think it will be easy.